# How can I implement an SQL query that group my output if the fields have the same values and add a new counter field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into SQL and I have the following problem.

I have to implement a simple SELECT query that return the list of all the records into a table, and it is very simple:

```
SELECT
    MD_CD.id,
    MD_CD.market_details_id,
    MD_CD.commodity_details_id
FROM MarketDetails_CommodityDetails         AS MD_CD
```

that return something like:

```
id                   market_details_id    commodity_details_id
--------------------------------------------------------------
177                  13                   41                  
178                  12                   43                  
179                  12                   13                  
180                  12                   11                  
181                  12                   38                  
182                  12                   39                  
183                  12                   40                  
184                  12                   42 
185                  12                   42
```

Ok my problem is that I want to group the rows having the same values into the **market_details_id** and the **commodity_details_id**. I want also add a counter of the number of these rows.

So for example, considering the last 2 rows I want that these rows are groupped in a single row and I want a new counter fiend containing the value 2 (because I have 2 rows with the same values of these 2 fields).

So I think that I want to obtain something like this:

```
                 market_details_id    commodity_details_id     counter
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  13                   41                       1                 
                  12                   43                       1                   
                  12                   13                       1                   
                  12                   11                       1                   
                  12                   38                       1                   
                  12                   39                       1                   
                  40                   40                        1                   
                  12                   42                       2
```

How can I implement this behavior in my query?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  You should also include the results you want in the question, if the answer is not so simple.

Comment: Group by clause and a new column as count (*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(MD_CD.id) As Counter,
    MD_CD.market_details_id,
    MD_CD.commodity_details_id
FROM MarketDetails_CommodityDetails  AS MD_CD
GROUP BY   MD_CD.market_details_id,  MD_CD.commodity_details_id
```

Comment: Ok, it works...I tried to add a WHERE Counter > 1 at the end of this query (to filter the query result) but it is not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: because using the WHERE clause as explained by you I obtain this error: "#42S22Unknown column 'counter' in 'where clause'"